# Reuse XAML in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have some XAML I want to reuse. I can easily create a custom control and use it, but I'd rather not. Here's what I've tried:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Expander x:Key="Namespacer" x:Shared="False" Name="NS"  Background="SkyBlue">
        <StackPanel Name="ClientArea" Margin="20,0,20,0">
            <StackPanel Name="Usings" Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="Structs" Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="Classes" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="IFaces" Grid.Row="3" Height="Auto"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="Delegates" Grid.Row="4" Height="Auto"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="Enums" Grid.Row="5" Height="Auto"></StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="Nested" Grid.Row="6" Height="Auto"></StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Name="N1" Content="{StaticResource Namespacer}" />

</StackPanel>
```

Now, I want to do something like:

```
this.N1.Header = "SomeTitle.Namespace1";
```

And also be able to add new chunks of XAML to my stack panels in N1 in a similar fashion. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could do this:

```
((Expander)(this.N1.Content)).Header = "SomeTitle.Namespace1";
```

But that gets ugly.  I'd recommend switching to data binding.  Here's an example.

First, here's a data class with the structure I think you're going for:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public class MyData
    {
      public string ItemTitle { get; set; }
      public IList<string> Usings { get; set; }
      public IList<string> Structs { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyViewModel
    {
      public IList<MyData> MyBoundData { get; set; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
      var d1 = new MyData{
        ItemTitle = "thing1",
        Usings = new[]{"a", "b"}
      };
      var d2 = new MyData{
        ItemTitle = "thing2",
        Structs = new[]{"c","d"}
      };
      this.DataContext = new MyViewModel{
        MyBoundData = new[]{ d1, d2}
      };
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
```

And here's an items control bound to our data:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyBoundData}" Focusable="False">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Expander Header="{Binding ItemTitle}" Background="SkyBlue">
            <StackPanel>
              <Expander Header="Usings"  Background="SkyBlue">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Usings}"/>
              </Expander>
              <Expander Header="Structs" Background="SkyBlue">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Structs}"/>
              </Expander>
            </StackPanel>
          </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note that the items control has a DataTemplate that corresponds to your "Namespacer" xaml chunk.  You could, of course, move the DataTemplate chunk into the window resources like you have in your example, if you want to use it in more than one ItemsControl.